# Anylogic - Strange routing behavior (Road Library)

Tags: anylogic

I have the following Road Network, I have a CarMoveTo block so that from point A goes to point B. The expected behavior is the one I draw with the green line, but the cars do is the route of the red line. I don't understand the reason, is there any way to configure it to choose the shortest route? or what could be

[image]

I tried to lower the speed, to avoid that more vehicles enter by the other way but it didn't work. I noticed, when using the getRoute function, that from the beginning it calculates that long route. I don't know what else to do. In addition, you can see how the car, being in the left lane, changes lanes to take the right lane and take the red route, the car could continue in its lane without any problem because there is no heavy traffic.

I have read some solutions where they put stopline to control the movement but I would like to understand the way AnyLogic calculates this to know if I have some error in the way of the track or it is some parameter that I can configure.

Comment: are you sure the green route exists?

Comment: Hello, yes, I am. In the event that I remove the circular exit ramp to prevent the car from exiting, it works fine.

Comment: that's what i mean, by adding the ramp, maybe you are also removing the path... try putting a stop line just after the crossing and send the car there just to be sure